# Setting image as font filling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, image, text, filling

Is it possible to use an image as a label font filling to have a result like in the following examples with national flags?

[image: Poland]
[image: Belarus]
[image: Romania]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to fill text elements with images, but IMHO it's limited to the QGIS layout. You can use HTML with CSS formatting to achieve the desired result.

[image]

And here's the example for the United States:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#title {
    background: url(https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/us.webp);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: 50%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title">
    <h1>United States</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `url(https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/us.webp)` and the desired country name accordingly.